# Explanation of Tuple<string, 10>

Tags: typescript

I found this type `Tuple<string, 10>` in [Mantine documentation](https://mantine.dev/theming/theme-object/) but I couldn't grasp the concept of it. I tested in TypeScript playground and it throws compile error.

```
 // Object of arrays with 10 colors
  colors: Record<string, Tuple<string, 10>>;
```

[image]

When I look up [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#tuple) there is no explanation about the first type in chevron is item type in array and the second number represents number of items in array. Can anyone share me some insight how this type definition works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at it in the [Github repository](https://github.com/mantinedev/mantine) of Mantine. `Tuple` is a custom type that is defined like this:

```
type _TupleOf<
  T,
  N extends number,
  R extends unknown[]
> = R["length"] extends N ? R : _TupleOf<T, N, [T, ...R]>;

export type Tuple<T, N extends number> = N extends N
  ? number extends N
    ? T[]
    : _TupleOf<T, N, []>
  : never;
```

As you can see, we're dealing with recursive types here. Essentially, `Tuple` produces an fixed-length array like structure structure. `Record<string, Tuple<string, 10>>` will be inferred to:

```
{
    [x: string]: [string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string, string];
}
```

Comment: Oh, I had no idea it was a custom type. Thanks a lot for the explanation!